# Missing { and } inserted

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

`pdflatex` keeps complaining about braces but they are balanced. I read that some environments start math mode automatically, but I don't think I'm using them.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Analisi I - Teoremi}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

\section{Limit Infiniti}
\newtheorem*{perm}{Teorema della permanenza del segno}
\begin{perm}
    Sia $\lim_\limits{x \to \alpha} f(x) = +\infty$ e $a > 0$. Allora esiste
    una semiretta su cui $f(x) > a > 0$.
\end{perm}
\begin{proof}
    Segue immediatamente dalla definizione. \qedhere
\end{proof}

\newtheorem*{confronto}{Teorema del confronto}
\begin{confronto}
    Sia $\lim_\limits{x \to \alpha} f(x) = +\infty$ e $g(x) \geq f(x)$. Allora
    $\lim_\limits{x \to \alpha} g(x) = +\infty$.
\end{confronto}
\begin{proof}
    \\[
        \begin{cases}
            f(x) &> \epsilon\\
            g(x) &\geq f(x)
        \end{cases} \implies g(x) > \epsilon
    \\]
\end{proof}
% section Limit Infiniti (end)

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar Unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what went wrong:

1. You didn't load `amsmath` but used `cases`.
2. `\lim_\limits{x...` should be `\lim\limits_{x..` i.e, `_` should come after `\limits` not before.
3. You have used `\\[....\\]` for display equation which should be `\[....\]`

Corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Analisi I - Teoremi}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

\section{Limit Infiniti}
\newtheorem*{perm}{Teorema della permanenza del segno}
\begin{perm}
    Sia $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = +\infty$ e $a > 0$. Allora esiste
    una semiretta su cui $f(x) > a > 0$.
\end{perm}
\begin{proof}
    Segue immediatamente dalla definizione. \qedhere
\end{proof}

\newtheorem*{confronto}{Teorema del confronto}
\begin{confronto}
    Sia $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = +\infty$ e $g(x) \geq f(x)$. Allora
    $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} g(x) = +\infty$.
\end{confronto}
\begin{proof}
    \[
        \begin{cases}
            f(x) > \epsilon\\
            g(x) \geq f(x)
        \end{cases} \implies g(x) > \epsilon
    \]
\end{proof}
% section Limit Infiniti (end)

\end{document}
```

The format for `cases` is

```
<case> & <condition>
```

and since you don't have any conditions here, no need of using `&` here and  `f(x) > \epsilon` gives proper spacing.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. I forgot about `amsmath`